# Как передать аргументы приложения через docker compose

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose

Я только начинаю работать с контейнерами docker

У меня в dotnet приложение необходимо передать множество аргументов, для того чтобы сконфигурировать его, и сделать это необходимо через docker compose, но у меня не особо получается

часть docker-compose файла:

```
scheduleservice:
     image: # link to dockerhub repos
     container_name: scheduleservice
     restart: always
     environment:
         - TZ=Asia/Yekaterinburg
         # *пробовал сюда писать аргументы, но приложение их не видит*
     # сделал отдельно Dockerfile (что считаю не правильным решением), но и оно не помогло
     build:
         context: .
         args:
             # здесь писал аргументы, но как сказал ранее, тут их приложение тоже не видело
     ports:
         - 5000:80
```

Также вот пример Dockerfile, который я написал

```
FROM #link to dockerhub repos

ARG arg1

ENV arg1 $arg1
```

И вот пример кода на C#, которым я пытался отловить аргументы

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(var arg in args)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался в данном вопросе, для того чтобы передать аргументы в приложение через docker compose file необходимо прописать их в поле command

Пример:

```
scheduleservice:
 image: # link to dockerhub repos
 container_name: scheduleservice
 restart: always
 environment:
     - TZ=Asia/Yekaterinburg
 command:
     # здесь прописывать аргументы, в любом формате, строчка полностью передаётся в аргумент
     sheetid=isdoif3asdkl456
 ports:
     - 5000:80
```

Answer (score 0):

В своем вопросе вы путаете **переменные командной строки** и **параметры окружения**.

Как передать переменную в командной строке уже ответили. В вашем тексте `TZ` это переменная окружения. Ее так же можно использовать. через [GetEnvironmentVariable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    tz= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TZ");
    Console.WriteLine(tz);
}
```